# Ticks option is ignored when plotting with Frame->True

Tags: plotting, ticks

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {{{4, "Here"}}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

```
x1 = Range[0, 10, 0.01];
y1 = Sin[x1];
ListLinePlot[Thread[{x1, y1}], Ticks -> {{{4, "Here"}}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

```
(* How to make this work? *)
ListLinePlot[Thread[{x1, y1}], Ticks -> {{{4, "Here"}}, Automatic}
     , Mesh -> Full, Frame -> True]
```

When I have `Frame -> True`, how can I make `Ticks` work like the first plot?

Comment: Take a look at `FrameTicks`.

Comment: @YvesKlett I understood the question as meaning that when `Frame -> True`, the axis ticks are (incorrectly?) no longer drawn and `Ticks` specification is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @YvesKlett suggested, I have sorted it out!

```
x1 = Range[0, 10, 2];
y1 = Sin[x1];
ListLinePlot[
Thread[{x1, y1}],

FrameTicks -> {
{Automatic, Automatic},
{Thread[{x1, Exp[x1] // N}], x1}
},
Mesh -> Full, Frame -> True]
```

`FrameTicks` does the trick!